# Attempted parent access of defined child protected property returns as undefined

Tags: php, class, static

Here is a mockup I did that represents what I'm essentially trying to do:

```
<?php
    abstract class parentClass
    {
        protected $classProp;

        static function showChildProps()
        {
            $childObj1 = new childClass1();
            $childObj2 = new childClass2();
            var_dump($childObj1);
            var_dump($childObj2);
            echo $childObj1->$classProp;
            echo $childObj2->$classProp;
        }
    }

    class childClass1 extends parentClass
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->classProp = 'Child Class 1';
        }
    }

    class childClass2 extends parentClass
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->classProp = 'Child Class 2';
        }
    }

    parentClass::showChildProps();
?>
```

This is an simplified version of what I'm trying to do, but the above code produces the exact result (and the `var_dump` is to show that the properties are defined).

The concept is that I have a multitude of classes extending the parent (I can mock some code  to show how I'm accomplishing that if it would be beneficial), and I want to show the list of those child classes (this portion is functional in the actual code) as well as the data assigned to a particular, common variable (`$classProp` in this case) for each of these classes.

If you run the provided code, you'll see that `var_dump` indicates that `$classProp` is indeed defined, however, when I attempt to access the property from the parent, I get PHP Notice:  Undefined variable.

My understanding from the PHP documentation is that protected properties are accessible via inherited or parent classes, yet I'm still getting this error. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are trying to do: use `echo $childObj1->classProp;`, not `echo $childObj1->$classProp;`

Comment: Wrikken: Much appreciated! That did the trick. I thought I tried that way earlier, but apparently not. Thanks again!